# How can i pass parameter to page factory method in selenium for specific search result?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml, page-factory

In my project, I got a bunch of search results. Now I want to click on a specific element, based on the user parameters.
used **page factory design pattern**.

> EbayPage.java - PageFatory

```
@FindBy(xpath="//h3[@class='s-item__title']")
List<WebElement> serachresults;
public List<WebElement> SearchResults() {
    return serachresults;
}
```

> EbayTest.java - Testcase

```
List<WebElement> products = ebp.SearchResults(); 
System.out.println("No of products on first page "+products.size());
for(int i=0;i<products.size();i++) {
System.out.println(products.get(i).getText());
} 
//**How can i handle this type of xpaths in Page Factory Model**
int no = 6;
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-view='mi:1686|iid:"+no+"']/div/div[@class='s-item__image-section']")).click();
System.out.println(no+" th product is: "+driver.getTitle());
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The standard page factory model may be too rigid for what you're trying to do as it creates pages object in contructor as soon as possible.

This may not be the answer you're looking for but if you really want to use component-based approach, check this project I created to address this and some other limitations of page factory (check project's wiki for examples):

https://bitbucket.org/rostislav_matl/aport/.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Take this as example and use it in your project:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='panel-body']/preceding-sibling::"
            + "div[text()='Radio Button Demo']/following-sibling::div")
private WebElement radioBtnGenderRadioButtonDemoXpath;

public void selectGenderMaleOrFemale(String gender) {
radioBtnGenderRadioButtonDemoXpath
                .findElement(By.xpath(".//label[contains(text(),'" + gender + "')]/input[1]")));
}
```